# Pushing view out of NSObject Class

Tags: ios, view, window, nsobject, mbprogresshud

How can i push a view from a class which is a child of NSObject to the screen/window?
At this moment I'm writing a class to sync the data in my app with the data on my server and i want to use the MBProgressHUD class.
The Problem is, that the sync class is a child of NSObject and I don't know, how to push something out of this class to the screen.

Or should i have edit the NSObject class completely to another kind of parent class?

Thanks,
teawithfruit

Answer (score 0):

I would present the HUD on your current view. If all the work is in your child class, use the -showWhileExecuting method and just call your child class, do all the work, then when it returns back, it will automatically dismiss the HUD.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIView property, do your graphics with that view, then, from the viewController, add the view property as a subview.